# Ajax Repeating form several time

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to add Ajax to my like button, and it is working except that when I press for the first time i is added.  When I press to unlike on more time it starts to automatically repeat itself several
times and the more I press the more repeated like and unlike.

This is the first time I have seen this error before

Here is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='liked', blank=True)
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is the views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/post_detail.html"  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(
            post=post).order_by('-id')
        total_likes = post.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                content = self.request.POST.get('content')
                comment_qs = None

                comment = Comment.objects.create(
                    post=post, user=self.request.user, content=content)
                comment.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("blog/post_detail.html")
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        context["comments"] = comments
        context["comment_form"] = comment_form
        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked

        return context

def LikeView(request):
    # post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True

    context = {
        'total_likes': post.total_likes,
        'liked': liked,
        'post': post
    }

    if request.is_ajax:
        html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Here is the main project url.py

```
    path('like/', views.LikeView, name='like_post'),
```

Here is the post-details.html

```
            <div id="like-section">
            {% include 'blog/like_section.html' %}
            </div>
```

here is the like_sections.html

```
    <form class="mt-0" action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
        : {{total_likes}} </strong>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if liked %}
            <br>
            <button type='submit' id='like' name='post_id' value="{{post.id}}" class= "btn btn-danger btn-sm" > No ! Don't Like it </button>
        {% else %}
            <br>
            <button type='submit' id='like' name='post_id' value="{{post.id}}" class= "btn btn-primary btn-sm"> Yes ! Like it </button>
        {% endif  %}
        {% else %}
        <p><small><a href="{% url 'login' %}"> Login</a> to Like </small></p>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
```

Here is the scripts

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        let display = false
        $(".cmt_btn").click(function () {
            if (display===false) {
                $(this).next(".comment-box").show("fast");
                display=true
            } else {
                $(this).next(".comment-box").hide("fast");
                display=false
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(event){
        $(document).on('click','#like', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var pk= $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'{% url "like_post" %}',
                data:{'id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':'{{csrf_token}}'},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(response){
                    $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
                    console.log($('#like-section').html(response['form']));
                },
                error:function(rs, e){
                    console.log(rs.responseText);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is an image from the console log:

[image]

Comment: Hi, put console inside your button event see if you press any button how many times it gets called

Comment: @Swati I am new at javascript so please bear with me, could you please guide me on how to console inside your button event

Comment: Simply do `console.log("i am in")` inside that handler see how many times this gets printed.